# How to save a Tensorflow model ( which doesnt contain any variable ) to port it in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, neural-network, opencv3.0, opencv3.1

I wanted to know what is the correct way to save a tensorflow model that I have trained in python so that I can import it in OpenCV using the dnn module of opencv. This is my Tensorflow graph

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,training_set.shape[1]],name = 'X')
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,training_labels.shape[1]], name = 'Y')

A1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(X, num_outputs = 50, activation_fn = tf.nn.relu)
A1 = tf.nn.dropout(A1, 0.8)
A2 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(A1, num_outputs = 2, activation_fn = None)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = A2, labels = Y))
global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
start_learning_rate = 0.001
learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(start_learning_rate, global_step, 100, 0.1, True )
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

As you can see it doesn't contain any variables. So my question is how should this graph be saved in Tensorflow so that it can be loaded using `cv::dnn::readNetFromTensorflow`. Should I save the model as `.pb` or `.pbtxt` file. And will the `.pb` or `.pbtxt` contain the graph as well as the weights or just the graph ??.  How to load both the graph and the weights in OpenCV ??.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that belongs to [OP posted link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/180458/how-should-a-tensorflow-model-be-saved-so-that-it-can-be-loaded-in-opencv331/) is posted here. URL may change, code renamed or vanished. Therefore I've posted the code to where it is referred by OP.

> I guess a first question is how to save the graph at least to load it in TensorFlow again? Because you need to find a way to restore it. There is some way to do it:

-- Save

```
# Save a graph definition (once)
tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph.as_graph_def(), "", "graph.pb")

# Weights initialization
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

# Training
...

# Save a checkpoint (weights only, no graph definition)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(sess, 'tmp.ckpt')
```

-- Freeze (merge graph definition with weights, remove training-only nodes)

```
python ~/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py \
  --input_graph=graph.pb \
  --input_checkpoint=tmp.ckpt \
  --output_graph=frozen_graph.pb \
  --output_node_names="NameOfOutputNode"
```

Only after these steps you might load frozen_graph.pb contains both graph definition and weights using OpenCV.